# How to find side given area, angle and another side?

Tags: trigonometry

In my question, it states that:

> In Triangle ΔABC  ∠C = 60º, b= 24cm and the area is 30cm$^2$, find the side a.

How can I solve this question, I have hit a dead end and am not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

Area of $\triangle =\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$

Here's the [Proof](https://www.math-only-math.com/area-of-a-triangle.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The area of a triangle can be computed as half of the product of any two sides and the sine of the angle between said sides.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which side you want to find. To find the other unknown side that includes the known angle, do as suggested in the other answers.

You can then use the cosine rule to find the final side.